# Nlog Target Database set connection information at runtime

Tags: c#, nlog

Using Nlog and a Database target, is there a way to set the connection information at runtime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I remember some colleague of mine doing something similar. He found this answer: http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/DDL-for-Database-Table-How-to-set-Connection-String-Programmatically-td5241103.html that was working perfectly fine.

From the link above

> The easiest way of overriding connection string is through the use of
>   GDC:

```
<target name="db" type="Database" connectionString="${gdc:myConnectionstring}" ... />
```

> Now in your code you can simply do:

```
GDC.Set("myConnectionString", "Server=.;database=.....");
```

> You can also modify the target:

```
var config = LogManager.Configuration;
var dbTarget = (DatabaseTarget)config.FindTargetByName("db");
dbTarget.ConnectionString = "server=.;...";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I couldn't find that.

Comment: Note that changing the dbProvider programmatically (and calling LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers afterwards) doesn't work, although it successfully changes connection string. Not sure whether it is a bug or feature.