# Setup Nlog unc path by project configuration file

Tags: c#, nlog

Say I defined the NLog target as:

```
<variable name="day" value="${date:format=dddd}"/>
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${verbose}" fileName="${basedir}/${day}.log" />
 </targets>
```

However I really want to place the file location at an app config file or other xml file. I don't know how to set up the unc path in the C# code programmatically rather than in NLog configuration file.

**Edit:**

Say the application will be distributed in 100 clients in different location in US. Each client would prefer its own log file location. The application has its own app.config or respective xml file to store its location. So it seems no way to hard code the locations in NLog configuration file.

Comment: not sure what you want or mean by the "hard code the locations". you want them hardcoded, or to programmatically set them ?

Comment: @Noctis, I meant that `{basedir}` was referred to the application folder(https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target). But in my case the clients would customize their own. For ex, client 1 would select "\\1111\log.txt", but client 2 would like "\\2222\log.txt". The information are save the xml file or app config. Yes, I want programmatically to set them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to do something similar with connection strings and DB targets ([this is my original question and self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499645/castle-and-nlog-change-connection-string-at-runtime), may add some additional help). Taking that solution with a little modifications you can try something like

> NOTES:
>  
>    1. this has not been tested but should get you close.
>    2. I am using Castle Windsor so this is why I have the factory class setup, you probably dont need all that, just the foreach

```
public class OwnNLogFactory : NLogFactory
{
    public OwnNLogFactory(string filePath)
    {
        foreach (var dbTarget in LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.OfType<FileTarget>().Select(aTarget => aTarget))
        {
            dbTarget.FileName = filePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, I realise this was asked a little while ago but stumbled on this looking for something else